# Any good choice for identifying missing datatype property values on Protege OWL?

Tags: owl, protege

I know that similar questions have been asked in different ways here but still I see no solution for it...

I would like to add a restriction which states that individuals of class A have exactly 1 data type property value. I have been trying i.e. inserting `hasXValue exactly 1` on equivalent classes Protege tab. Also, I have tried also combining `min` and `max` restrictions. However, as stated by other people´s posts, it is consistent to have 0 or 1 declaration of value but not 2. I have understood some explanations about the world assumption in OWL but then I would like to know which kind of axiom it could be used for doing this restriction.

In fact, the easiest solution that worked for me is by querying within a SPARQL ASK query, looking the no existence of an instance that pertains to certain class and does not have a data type property value (I have use FILTER NON EXISTS). In this way, I can have a true/false value stating that there is or not any individual with no data type property value declaration. However, I would like the reasoner to say that the model is inconsistent in this case.

My objective is that if I have to declare a lot of instances of a class that must have i.e. an ID, not miss any declaration. Moreover, I would like not having to execute a query for checking it. Thus, I though that cardinality restrictions were the correct choice.

Any help on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `a` has type `hasXValue exactly 1`, then `a` *does* have *exactly* one value for the property `hasXValue`.  It can't have 0, and it can't have 2.  It might not be the case that some particular data *contains* that assertion though.  OWL doesn't equate "I don't know that P" with "P is false."

Comment: I just asked because when I do this axiom declaration, seems to not giving me the expected result. I understand what you mean, thanks. I am wondering... Are you familiar with SWRL? Do you think that the use of SWRL could anyhow be helpful for this kind of validations? It could be an option to state that certain instance is not from a type unless it has certain data type property assertion, right? (May be I am over-complicating the whole concept...)

Comment: I don't think SWRL will help much here, either.  SWRL rules only operate on named individuals, and that might get in the way.  However, you *could* do something like: *A(?x) ∧ foo(?x,?y) → HasFooValue(?x)*.  Then if you end up with any A's that aren't *known* to be a *HasFooValue*, those might be ones that you want to investigate.  You'd still need a closed world reasoning to find those, though.

Comment: Indeed I think that that example could work. Thanks for your interesting viewpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to use OWL for validation, which requires a closed world interpretation of the semantics to get the kind of inconsistency errors you'd like to see.  As you've noticed, out of the box, you're not going to get that behavior because that's not what OWL was designed for.

There was a [workshop](http://www.w3.org/2012/12/rdf-val/) on this exact topic, and now there is a [W3C working group](http://www.w3.org/2014/data-shapes/wiki/Main_Page) to explore how to do validation in a standardized way.

[Stardog](http://stardog.com)'s implementation of integrity constraints uses OWL (Manchester) syntax, amongst others, for authoring constraints, which you could create in Protege, but Stardog itself doesn't have a Protege plugin.  As an aside, it translates constraints into SPARQL queries which use FILTER NOT EXISTS much in the same manner as you did by hand, except that it does so automatically.

Other inputs to the working group are SPIN and SHEX.  SHEX is not worth looking at, but SPIN could be another decent option for you.  It won't, as far as I know, work with Protege, but it is integrated with an IDE (TopBraid) and has a SPARQL based syntax.

Comment: Well, thanks for your detailed answer. I will go through the sources that you have cited and hopefully find another solution. If not, I will keep going with the ASK queries for this kind of validation!